# Validating WPF Visual Tree

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, controltemplate

I am trying to enforce that any new style added should have to meet some standards.  Here is a simple example.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CellValuePresenter}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CellValuePresenter}}">
 <Setter Property="Tag" Value="1"></Setter>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />              
          ....
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Updated**:

I am trying to validate the style from code behindthat if the style has ControlTemplate, its root should be Border with BorderThickness template binded.

Since Visual Tree is not created until the Control is rendered, I am creating the control at runtime based on target type and applying the style.  And I even tried the following 
[Appropriate way to force loading of a WPF Visual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224986/appropriate-way-to-force-loading-of-a-wpf-visual?lq=1)

I can see the visual tree in WPF Tree Visualizer, but I cannot navigate fully using `LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren`

I am just experimenting with ideas around:

```
    private void ValidateStyle(Style fieldStyle_, Field field_)
    {
      if (fieldStyle_.TargetType == typeof(CellValuePresenter))
      {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        CellValuePresenter presenter = new CellValuePresenter();
        presenter.Style = fieldStyle_;

        if (fieldStyle_.Setters.Count > 0)
        {
          foreach (Setter setter in fieldStyle_.Setters)
          {
           if (setter.Property != null && setter.Property.PropertyType == typeof(ControlTemplate))
            {
              presenter.ApplyTemplate();
              ValidateColumnStyle(0, presenter);
            }
          }             
        }
      }
    }

    private void ValidateColumnStyle(int depth_, object obj_)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine(new string(' ', depth_) + obj_);
      if (!(obj_ is DependencyObject))
      {
        return;
      }

      if (obj_ is UIElement)
      {
        Viewbox vb = new Viewbox() {Child = obj_ as UIElement};
        vb.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
        vb.Arrange(new Rect(vb.DesiredSize));
      }

      foreach (object child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj_ as DependencyObject))
        ValidateColumnStyle(depth_ + 1, child);
    }
```

I am not able to navigate to Border element, any idea how to properly load the control.

Comment: You would have to apply the Style to a Button in order for the ControlTemplate's visual tree to be constructed (and possibly call ApplyTemplate on the Button). Even then, it would only be set for the Button.ControlTemplate property, not in the Style.