# Why UIHelper.FindVisualParent<MainWindow>(this) returns null sometimes?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have MainWindow and User Controls inside each Tab.
When I am switching too fast between tabs or sometimes even without switching I get null in main;

```
var main = UIHelper.FindVisualParent<MainWindow>(this);
```

Why does this happens do you know?
Let's say it shows error such as main is null once in 7-10 tries.
I am using it in User Controls to get access to controls of MainWindow.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this special case I would use `var main = Application.Current.MainWindow;` to get MainWindow.

Comment: You have to wait till your UserControl has been added to the VisualTree i.e. after the Template has been applied....so that you can then navigate up the hierarchy...see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768945/wpf-force-to-build-visual-tree

Comment: @LPL It did not return anything in my case. I used it.

Comment: [Application.MainWindow Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx) should give you "a reference to the first Window object to be instantiated in the AppDomain."

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait till your `UserControl` has been added to the `VisualTree` i.e. after the Template has been applied....the easiest way to do that is wait till the `Loaded` event has been fired.

Then you can safely navigate up the hierarchy and look for your `MainWindow`.

Bear in mind though, that with the `TabControl` when you switch tabs, the tabs that disappear will unload their Visual content.

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/30e26229-beb5-4146-9493-09c3e158c45e

Thus you might need to watch the `Unloaded` event on your `UserControl` to ensure you don't call `VisualTreeHelper` when you are no longer in the VisualTree.

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/23dc9bcd-e8bc-4dae-96b9-d36dbbf9fe03

If you want to prevent the unload behaviour then you can modify the TabControl behaviour...but the original `TabControl` is designed like that to efficiently create visuals.

- [WPF TabControl - Preventing Unload on Tab Change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601125/wpf-tabcontrol-preventing-unload-on-tab-change)